# Should I avoid using "!" in if statement in Java?

Tags: java

Our team's Java Coding Guideline says:

> Avoid using "!" in if statement as much as possible.

I have asked other colleagues, but no one gave me clear ideas why, because the guideline was created a long time ago and the author might have left our company.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: The only reason I can think might have to do with readability

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Thanks. Um... I firstly thought using "!" is simpler and easy to read... is it the matter of sense or way of thinking?

Comment: I think `if (notTrue) {}` is more easy to read than `if (!true) {}`

Comment: There will be no valid reason to stop using `!` in codes other than readability (*that too when you over used*). There are obvious cases to use it. But use it whenever you need it only.

Comment: @Kenju There's no "complying" reason (from a performance point of view), so the only thing I can think of is the author had a preferred bias towards not using them.  This could be for readability, beyond `!` itself, as it would structure the code in a particular way. But that's just guess work

Comment: I find !quite confusing. Because you have to *Remember. Where as I can see blah == true. Definitely personal preference

Comment: @Antony Now I see what MadProgrammer said.  Do you think is the guideline usual and standard in Java world?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775379/using-not-operator-in-if-conditions

Comment: @Kenju - You're going to have style rules at any company. If you don't your principal/senior dev will want you to provide something he's used to. However, looks like industry is getting better with things like stylecop and such

Comment: I think I got the point... thank you all.

Comment: You could use `if (someBoolean&false)` to avoid `!` :-).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the information provided, this calls for some speculation.  One possible reason is that the intent was not for an if-statement by itself but for an if-else statement.  In that case, I can see where you might say that you should reverse the cases so that you don't have the extra operation of the negation.  Instead of

```
if (! boolVar) {
  // Something
} else {
  // Something else
}
```

you might prefer

```
if (boolVar) {
  // Something else
} else {
  // Something
}
```

Whether this is worth it or not is probably more a matter of taste and standardization than anything else.

Answer (score 6):

The rule is likely an adaptation from Robert Martin's *Clean Code*, page 302:

> Negatives are just a bit harder to understand than positives.  So, when possible, conditionals should be expressed as positives.  For example:
>
> ```
> if(buffer.shouldCompact())
> ```
>
> is preferable to
>
> ```
> if(!buffer.shouldNotCompact())
> ```

As an example, suppose you're creating a validator that requires two things to be false for the entity to be valid:

- The entity must not have been created within the last 12 hours, and
- The entity's bank account total sum must not exceed $50,000.

Naturally the idea would be to write two methods for this:

```
boolean isCreatedWithinLastTwelveHours(BankAccount account)
boolean hasMoreThanTotalSumCap(BankAccount account)
```

...at which point, you then invoke these as:

```
boolean newAccount = isCreatedWithinTheLastTwelveHours(account);
boolean highEndAccount = hasMoreThanTotalSumCap(account);

if(!newAccount && !highEndAccount) { // ... other logic

// The more astute would use DeMorgan's law in an effort to make this more readable

if(!(newAccount || highEndAccount)) { // other logic
```

Well...wouldn't it be nicer if you just said what they *weren't* instead?

```
boolean isNotCreatedWithinLastTwelveHours(BankAccount account)
boolean hasLessThanTotalSumCap(BankAccount account)
```

That'd make the expression a bit more concise:

```
if(notNewAccount && notHighEndAccount) { // .. carry on!
```

Comment: Those two conditionals operate under different circumstances it's not two different ways to say the same thing.

Comment: I thought so but I was questioning my sanity.

Answer (score 1):

Of course "!" can be used when you like. There is no "unless" in java and you have no other choices in some conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like yet-another-useless-rule. Generally speaking, there are no absolute terms in this scenario, true that if you are in a if-else clause then possibly it is better to write

```
if(myCondition) {
    doThis()
} else {
    doSomethingElse()
}
```

Instead of

```
if(!myCondition) {
   doSomethingElse()
} else {
   doThis()
}
```

However, that said, in some scenarios is actually quite ok to use the negation operator, particularly if no else clause is provided, example

```
if (!tokenDoesCompute()) {
   throw InvalidTockenException("Whatever")
}
```

And actually in that scenario, using "!" makes quite a bit of sense for me.

Finally, if no one can really explain WHY the rule is there, maybe it is time to remove it, the only good reason I could find for it would be to provide consistency regarding the code style.

Comment: I'm sure that the if-then-else scenario is the reason.  In a case like that, I definitely prefer `if(expr)` to `if(!expr)`.  But it looks like someone took that one case and either went overboard turning it into a simple rule, or just got extremely sloppy and didn't explain what they meant.  I've seen this sort of thing happen way too often, though.  _Sigh_..............

Comment: Your second example makes no sense "if(!tokenDoesNotCompute)" so token does compute, then throw an exception? This proves that the negation operator can be confusing sometimes... :).

Comment: @MathiasBegert you are absolutely right, I fixed it. (thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I answer my own question.
As other say, maybe this is written for the readability.

In [*The Art of Readable Code*](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=emiCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=readable+code+null&source=bl&ots=tGrIuvM6rO&sig=yXVzhXnnkQw57rQTcrWVmqWwoe8&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=readable%20code%20null&f=false) (p. 72) says:

> Prefer dealing with the positive case first instead of the negative-e.g., `if(debug)` instead of `if(!debug)`

I found below post as well:

- [Readable Code - Remove Checking null](http://cprogrammers.blogspot.jp/2008/11/readable-code-remove-checking-null.html)

  ```
  bool func(String name)
  {
      if ( (name != null) && (name.equals("true") ) {
          //...
      } else {
          //...
      }
  }
  ```

  ```
  bool func(String name)
  {
      if ( "true".equals(name) ) {
         //...
      } else {
          //...
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can use the negation operator `!` whenever you like.

However, if you have a situation where you have to write some actions in both `if` and `else` block then the following is more readable :

```
if(status){
//do something
}
else{
//do something else
}
```

than

```
if(!status){
//do something
}
else{
//do something else
}
```

But if you have situation where you only need to perform certain actions based on just one condition, i.e. if you have only an `if` block & no `else` block, then it is reasonably fine to use `!` in `if`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anyone else suggest this, which is probably because they hate it as much as I do, but I'm showing it for completeness.

```
// Using not operator (preferred)
if (! someTest) { ... }

// Using compact not operator (kind of hides it)
if (!someTest) { ... }

// Comparing to false (ok, explicitly states what you want)
if (someTest == false) { ... }

// Comparing to true (a bit obscure)
if (someTest != true) { ... }
```

They all do the same, but please keep using `!`, just make sure you add a space after it, so it's easier to see.